# Reduce the clickable area of the label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the example below, if I use a label as `<label class="radio">` and click area for the radio button it expands to the full width of the page.

Clicking outside this label (next to it inline) still trigger the radios button.

I tried label class as `inline`. But the radio buttons are arranged in a single
line.

Is there any other bootstrap `class` that can be used for radio buttons/label to have them in next lines with fixed label width?

This is my code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
      <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
      <form>
        <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The question is tagged Boostrap 4, but you're referencing Bootstrap 3. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can do for desktop:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
  <form style="display: grid">
    <label class="radio col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio col-sm-2">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3
    </label>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

:view fullpage.

Comment: This is not solving the issue